# MVC Bundles: How to add assets in views and have them render combined with the main layout page bundle

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In the telerik scriptregistrar and also the cassette package, you can add scripts from views and partials and have them registered and **combined** with the rest of the scripts in the main layout page and have them all render correctly at the end of the page together. Can this be done in the same way in MVC 4? So far, I don't see how to add additional bundles from views to the main bundle to be combined and minimified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done out of the box in MVC4. Sticking with Cassette